# Can not using get_header() cause trouble (later on)?

Tags: hooks

Can not using `get_header()` cause trouble (later on)?

I can think of several reasons of not using `get_header()`, for example if you would be making a one page website or you want to use some other php templating system or you want your header.php to be in a subfolder.

I know get_header() is basically the same as get_template_part() except for the fact that it does a `do_action('get_header')` (and uses require_once).

So the real question would be can not having `do_action('get_header')` inside of your template cause trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the `wp_head()` function is still being called in the template, you should be fine.

You've pretty much summed it up in your question; by not using `get_header()`, the `get_header` action will not be fired, but that wouldn't matter for your particular use case.

Using `get_header()` along with the name parameter would be the more "WordPress way" of doing it though:

`get_header( 'single-page-app' );`

Would use the file `header-single-page-app.php`. `get_header()` uses `locate_template()` internally, which does not search sub directories, so this approach would not be suitable for your use case.

Comment: So basically the only problem I could run into is when I would install a plugin that uses the get_header hook? Which can easily be fixed by calling it manually.

Comment: Yes, since `get_header()` runs the `get_header` action, anything that uses the `get_header` action would no longer work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's exactly what I needed to know.